# Query string embeded with bool query

Tags: elasticsearch

HI iam using the following query with bool must

```
{
  "query": { 
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [ {
      "match" : {
        "orgid" : {
          "query" : 13831,
          "type" : "boolean"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "query_string" : {
        "query" : "*07* AND *fres*"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
}
```

It's hitting null even though there documents with org id as 13831 & in documents there is one data in all fields as 07 and fres.Is anything wrong in this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: A problem might be you're using a match query instead of a term query. Term queries are used for exact matches. The following will filter the result set to only the org_id you want, and it will then look for 07 and fres. Please give it a try.

```
"query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "*07* AND *fres*"
         }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term" : { "orgid" : 13831 }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but my need is to get the documents with orgid:13831 AND that document must also contain characters like 07 AND fres in any of the fields in that document

Comment: if i wrote the above query as "orgid" : 13831
        } it will return all the documents in which orgid is 13831 but how about the 07 AND fres condition

Comment: I didn't say to remove the other condition. What does this return:
`{
  "query": { 
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [ {
      "match" : {
        "orgid" : 13831
      }
    }, {
      "query_string" : {
        "query" : "*07* AND *fres*"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
}`

Comment: Thanks, pqqash.....Both query  worked i was checking with wrong orgId,even my query was fine it was just a wrong orId ,Thank for your help